# Should we Use $(document).ready() inside a self invoking function(IIFE) for binding the events to HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, closures, document-ready, iife

There are Two implementation I am confused between :-

```
 - **FIRST**
// A self invoking function
selfFunction = (function(){

     $(document).ready(function(){        
          applyBindings();
      });

     applyBindings = function(){           
        $("#btnSubmit").on("click",function(){//Do Something});
        .....
        .....
        .....
        //More Bindings
     };
})();


- **SECOND**
 // A self invoking function
 selfFunction = (function(){

      applyBindings();      

      applyBindings = function(){           
        $("#btnSubmit").on("click",function(){//Do Something});
        .....
        .....
        .....
        //More Bindings
      };
})();
```

The Only difference is that in FIRST case I am binding the events using $(document).ready(). Where as in SECOND I am calling a function inside a Self invoking function.

Both are getting the work done, but I want to know which one should be followed and why??

Comment: The self invoking functions are irrelevant here. The point of using them is to create a scoped environment so you can create a bunch of variables with `var` to avoid polluting the global scope. You don't use `var` so all your variables end up as globals anyway.

Comment: The second example won't work. You call `applyBindings` before you assign a value to it. It should throw an error because `undefined` is undeclared at the time you call it.

Comment: @nishaant-sharma.  Could you clarify what would constitute an answer to your question? As far as I can tell, I have answered your it. Did you perhaps already have another (kind of) answer in mind? Just curious.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that using `$(document).ready(callback)` will work even if your js file was loaded (leading to the IIFE being executed) before the elements you apply bindings to had been rendered. (Maybe because some complex page structure, slow loading pictures or something similar).

Like the name suggests, `$(document).ready(callback)`, guaranties that your function will not run until the document is.. ready. So you can be sure that, for example, the element with id `btnSubmit` exists.  (Assuming it's part of the original HTML, ie. **not** being dynamically created elsewhere in the code).

To be clear, this

```
$("#btnSubmit")
```

is the part where it could break down. Beacuse if the button doesn't exist yet, then it doesn't matter that the *click* will definitely not come before the button exists. The event-listener specified by the rest of the code following  `$("#btnSubmit")` (ie the `.on("click", callback)`) will not be applied to the button, because there is no button (yet).

So the `$(document).ready(callback)` version is safer in more circumstances.

Comment: i am using event delegation to bind the events, So that id Existence problem won't be a problem.

Comment: I see, but in the more general case I still suspect my answer is why it's common to see (and prefer) the `$(document).ready(callback)` implementation (even if it's redundant in your specific case).

Comment: I now think maybe event delegation (if you mean that the callback doesn't get call until after the click event) doesn't save you. I've updated my answer.